# How to access a value from an array of objects in localStorange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to access a value of an array of objects in Javascript and then update it.

How can I do this?

My array of objects in localstorange:

```
[{"task":"study","completed":false,"createdDate":"Sat, 30 Jan 2021 18:24:44 GMT","id":"9153"},{"task":"programming","completed":false,"createdDate":"Sat, 30 Jan 2021 18:24:40 GMT","id":"0"}]
```

My code:

```
const Edit = ({ todo, setEdit, setEditInput, editInput }) => {

  const inputTextHandler = (e) => {
    setEditInput(e.target.value);
  }
  
  const updateTask = () => {
    let todoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
    setEdit(false); // remove the input and show the task value
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={editInput} onChange={inputTextHandler} autoFocus />
      <button onClick={updateTask}>
        <i className="fas fa-save"></i>
      </button>
    </div>    
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the array to memory. Do your modifications. Turn it to string and add it back to local storage.

```
// Load to memory
var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'))    
// Update todos
todos[0].completed = true
// Stringify and add it back to local storage
localStorage.setItem('todos',JSON.stringify(todos))
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create some utility functions to do it. Like this

```js
// utils/localStorage.js
export function getItem(keyName) {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(keyName));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}

export function setItem(keyName, value) {
  localStorage.setItem(keyName, JSON.stringify(value));
}

export function removeItem(keyName) {
  localStorage.removeItem(keyName);
}

export function clearAll() {
  localStorage.clear();
}
```